# Checkbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table which has a checkbox to select, and pagination is also there for the table. My problem is that if I select two boxes from first page and select few more in the second, only the boxes which i selected in the last page are getting displayed and the others are not coming. Please answer me if u are aware.

Here is my code :

```
function getSelectedEquipmentIds() {
        var equipmentIds = "";
        var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("instance");
        for ( var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
                equipmentIds += checkboxs[i].value + ";";
            }
        }
        return equipmentIds;
    }
```

Comment: what kind of pagination we are talking about, is it client side or server side ? i

Comment: you cannot have the data of you previous page on your new page,as soon as you go to new page that old data will be lost if you are going from one web page to another web page

Comment: You can do by saving it in `hiddenfield` , then first pull values from hidden field and then selected from current pagination page index

Comment: its client side pagination only

Comment: Please share you client side pagination code also. Or if easy crate jsFiddle for this

Comment: @Satinder singh ok i will try it